# BigQuery error with joins

Tags: sql, bigdata, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

do you know why this wont work in bigquery?

```
SELECT TOP(Score.goals, 10), COUNT(*)
FROM [cloude-sandbox:public.match_goals_table] AS Score left JOIN 
     [cloude-sandbox:public.match_games_table] AS Teams
     ON Teams.team_name = Score.goals;
```

Query Failed
Error: Join keys goals (int64) and team_name (string) have types that cannot be automatically coerced.

Comment: The error is pretty clear.  Either choose the right columns for the `JOIN`.  Or, coerce the two columns that do not seem to be meant to be joined together into the same type.

Answer (score 4):

BQ requires that the join key types match exactly. You can wrap one side of the join in a subquery to perform the conversion with minimal performance cost:

```
SELECT TOP(Score.goals, 10), COUNT(*)
FROM
  (SELECT goals, STRING(goals) AS goals_str
   FROM [cloude-sandbox:public.match_goals_table]) AS Score
LEFT JOIN 
  [cloude-sandbox:public.match_games_table] AS Teams
ON Teams.team_name = Score.goals_str;
```

I selected goals from the left side of the join as both an integer and a string so that you can join on the string but compute TOP on the integer.

But did you really mean to join on the team name and the goal count? Maybe this is just an example, but that join seems unlikely to produce any output.